# visual studio 2012 RC Could not load type System.Web.Http.RouteParameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2012

I had VS 11 Beta, .net 4.5 and MVC 4 beta installed on my PC. I just downloaded the latest RC and now I get this error message when I try to run web projects. I tried reinstalling .net 4.5 and uninstalling and resinstalling VS 12 RC but that hasn't worked. I tried the 
suggestion [here](http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2012/04/06/building-the-source-code-of-asp-net-web-api/) which didn't work either.

**Stack**

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Source Error:


Line 26:                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
Line 27:             );
Line 28:         }
Line 29:     }
Line 30: }


Source File: c:\projects\testNew\testNew\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs    Line: 28

Stack Trace:


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   testNew.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in c:\projects\testNew\testNew\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:28
   testNew.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\projects\testNew\testNew\Global.asax.cs:25

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9841101
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9850940
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17626
```

**Edit 6**

I used `fuslogvw` and found out that the project was referencing the `System.Web.Http.dll` from here

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
```

instead of my project. Renaming this file made my project work but I obviously can't do this on my shared hosting site.

I've manually referenced the dll from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies
```

and set it to `Copy to Local`. Still it loads from `gac_msil`. How do I override this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now the answer is to replace the dll from the folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies
```

into

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
```

upgrading over top of the Beta to the RC worked on another machine. I hope this helps someone in the future.

I'll update if I find a better answer

Comment: Yes it works. @FatAlbert Make sure you replace all assemblies including XMLs

Comment: System.Web.Http does not exist underneath the GAC_MSIL for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and found this question while googling on the error. 
When I looked at the installed programs on my windows, I saw there were 3 MVC 4 'applications' installed:

1. MVC 4 VS 2010 Tools
2. MVC 4
3. MVC 4 (Bundle)

I uninstalled the "MVC 4" application and then my projects worked fine.

Comment: thanks for the addition @roet. I had already uninstalled everything I could find at the point I had created this question. It didn't work for me but I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you also upgrade from MVC4 Beta to MVC4 RC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4
And according to the release notes: ' You can upgrade the ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview and Beta to ASP.NET MVC 4 Release Candidate without uninstalling.'

And I did just that and got rid of the error.

The reason is your app is pointing to the old MVC4 Beta in the GAC.

An alternative is using the DEVPATH environment variable mentioned at this link.
http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2012/04/06/building-the-source-code-of-asp-net-web-api/

Vincent

Comment: I already tried the DEVPATH as I mentioned in my OP. MVC 4 RC comes with 2012 RC. There is no option to download this separately for 2012. Also see newest edits