# C# MVC routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

In my Global.asax.cs I have this codes

```
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

each time I run the application there is a break on the above line with this error:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

What do you think would resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual studio 2012 RC Could not load type System.Web.Http.RouteParameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939239/visual-studio-2012-rc-could-not-load-type-system-web-http-routeparameter)

Comment: @musefan I'm running Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: So none of those answers solve you problem then?

Comment: I have gone through the suggested answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939239/visual-studio-2012-rc-could-not-load-type-system-web-http-routeparameter with out any solution.

Comment: @musefan, yes, none answer my question. I started having this when I did some installations on nuget packages. The problem is, O installed about 6 packages. Having to uninstall all that will give me another issue.

Comment: install or register mvc in visual studio and windows