# The type or namespace "HTTPGet" could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio to code in C#.
This is my part of code where I have some problems:

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet();
req.Request("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
string[] a = req.ResponseBody.Split(':');
string a2 = a[1].Substring(1);
string[] a3 = a2.Split('<');
string a4 = a3[0];
label3.Text = "Public IP Address: " + a4;
```

That's what I included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Management;
using static System.Object;
using System.Net.Http;
```

And I still get this error:

> The type or namespace "HTTPGet" could not be found.

What can I do?

Comment: @KobyDouek The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this a MVC project? Webforms? Winforms?

Comment: @KobyDouek Windows Forms Application

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311044/the-type-or-namespace-name-httpget-could-not-be-found-when-add-system-web-htt)

Comment: Hmm... still don't know what to do

Comment: Where did you get that code from? There’s no `HttpGet` type in the CLR.

Comment: `HttpGet` isn't a class.  `HttpGetAttribute` *is* a class, but it isn't used to make requests.

Comment: Searched on internet on how to get a public IP address in Visual C#. Found this

Comment: … do you have a link to your source?

Comment: It's a complete mystery what was intended with this code. I can't locate any framework types with a `ResponseBody` property. Are you sure it wasn't just someone's sketch/pseudo-code?

Comment: Maybe I found the source?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838551/47589

Comment: That's it, Amy.

Comment: @poke - it's a broken link, as one commenter already mentioned on that answer.

Comment: you know what your code need to do ? :), what you trying to achieve, make a quastion not a pointer to some problem you have

Comment: Yup. Take the user's public IP, make it a string and show it in a label.

Comment: A working method?

Comment: Just [choose another answer from the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address).

Comment: Well you could look at the other answers to that question.....

Comment: Made it! Thanks, anyway. I was struggling with HTTPGet

Comment: So let me understand.  You chose an answer that you couldn't get working.  Instead of choosing another answer on that question, you asked for help with it, despite the comments on the original answer, and you don't mention that answer here?  Meanwhile the original question has an accepted answer, and that isn't the answer you chose.  Is that the gist of it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you want create http request through GET. also you need something similar to HttpWebRequest:

[C# how to properly make a http web GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108264/c-sharp-how-to-properly-make-a-http-web-get-request)

or maybe you mix up with attributes [Understanding [HttpPost], [HttpGet] and Complex Actionmethod parameters in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776486/understanding-httppost-httpget-and-complex-actionmethod-parameters-in-mvc)